# Woocommerce: add 'Free Delivery' badge to product thumbnail in Woocommerce based on shipping class

Tags: woocommerce, badge

i want add, on product listing, over image a text badge "Free delivery" based on specific shipping class "spedizione-gratuita".
You can help me ?

I test this code but dont work

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'single_product_label', 10 );
function single_product_label() {
   global $product;
   $shipping_classes  = 'spedizione-gratuita';
    if (  $product->get_shipping_class() )  {

        echo '<div class="spedizione-gratuita"><span class="freedel">SPEDIZIONE GRATUITA</span></div>';
        
    }
  }
```

Tnks

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will achieve what you are trying to do. You almost had it, but the $product global has no value in the shop loop you need to use $post instead

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'single_product_label', 10 );
function single_product_label() {
   global $post;
   $_product = wc_get_product( $post->ID );
    
   $shipping_classes  = 'spedizione-gratuita';
   if ( $shipping_classes == $_product->get_shipping_class() )  {

        echo '<div class="spedizione-gratuita"><span class="freedel">SPEDIZIONE GRATUITA</span></div>';
        
   }
}
```

Comment: Tnk u @jtowell.

Comment: @ispreadtoyou if you are happy with the answer can you please mark it as the accepted answer. Thanks